# Shallow from Enzyme not rendering the jxs component and just returns an empty object

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have this unit test here :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import FilterBtn from '../components/FilterBtn';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
        
describe('Render Header', () => {
  const props = {
    restaurantData: {},
    showSideMenu: false,
  }
        
  it('should render Header correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Header {...props} />);
                
    expect(wrapper.find('header__container')).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('img')).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(<FilterBtn />)).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(<SearchBar />)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Whenever I run and `npm run test` this is what I get back:

[image]

The shallow keeps just returning and empty `{}`
This is what the header comp looks like :

```js
export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <div className="header__container">
       <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="header__logo" />
       <div className="header__search">
         <FilterBtn
           toggleSort={props.toggleSort}
           sortRestaurants={props.sortRestaurants}
           restaurantData={props.restaurantData}
         />
         <SearchBar 
           handleResults={props.handleResults}
           showSideMenuToggle={props.showSideMenuToggle}
           showSideMenu={props.showSideMenu}
         />
       </div>
     </div>
   )
};
```

Why is it just returning an empty `{}` and not the component? I've tried mount as well doesn't work either. Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a dot in your selector. In this case, the `.head__container` refers to a class name. See examples below:

```
const Header = () => (
  <div 
    data-testid="header_data_id" 
    id="header_id" 
    className="header_class"
  >
   test
  </div>
);

const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);

// className
expect(wrapper.find(".header_class")).toHaveLength(1);

// id
expect(wrapper.find("#header_id")).toHaveLength(1);

// HTML element
expect(wrapper.find("div")).toHaveLength(1);

// HTML attribute
expect(wrapper.find("[data-testid='header_data_id']")).toHaveLength(1);

// React component
expect(wrapper.find(Header)).toHaveLength(1);

// React component display name
// this is not very consistent and may/may not have a different display name
// use the above selectors first before using this one
expect(wrapper.find("Header")).toHaveLength(1);
```

Do not use JSX as selectors! View the [enzyme selector docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html) for supported queries.